# com.sonarsource.A.A.B.A: No license for swift Error on sonar

Tags: sonarqube, swift

I was scanning a swift project on my sonar server.And at the end of the scan I got this error.

> com.sonarsource.A.A.B.A: No license for swift

All the other .Net and Java projects are working fine. Only the issue is with swift project.

```
sonar.projectKey=VendorCompar-iOS
sonar.projectVersion=$BUILD_NUMBER
sonar.projectName=VendorCompar - iOS
sonar.sources=.
sonar.verbose=true
sonar.log.level=TRACE
#sonar.language=swift
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 3):

The Swift plugin is a commercial plugin and you need a licence to be able to analyze swift projects : https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarswift.html

Comment: Link only answers are subject to be removed. Please add some description to your answer.

Comment: This not a link only answer. I think the answer is correct. In this case it is short, but contains the information needed. Namely, buy a license.

Comment: I agreed woth Niels and Eric.So dont i have any free way to scan my SWIFT code?

Comment: There is an alternative : if your code is opensource you can analyze it for free on https://sonarcloud.io/, note that there is a paid plan if it's closed source.